# Date picker not showing december month

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using below jquery to show date picker I have multiple date select box. It is working properly .However it is not showing december month. Please help me here is my code

```
$('.datepicker').live('focus',function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1900:' + new Date().getFullYear(),
        maxDate: 0
     })
 });
```

Comment: why do you set `maxDate: 0`?

Comment: @AnthonyC have  added maxDate = 0 so that it should not show future date.

Comment: please share your js on https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you have to do is add +2 to the maximum date, so I will let you see the month of December, if you put -1 it will take away a month, it may be the current month, I had the same problem and so it was corrected. maxDate: "+ 2M".

[image: This will show the calendar when applying +2.]

Answer (score 0):

having maxDate = 0 is the reason you don't see Dec in the month drop down since this question was posted in Nov. If you pick a different year, you will be able to see Dec in the month drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue it was due to  maxDate: 0.
I have changed maxDate: -1 to solve the issue.
Thanks @kimdung and @Anthony C you you kind help